# Add char to the middle of the Array of string

Tags: c

I need to add dots('.') and other chars, to the middle of the string, I can't figure out how to do it. For example, the user types 12345678900, I need to print 123.345.678-00

This is the Array part:

```
#define MAX 100

struct cadastro
{
  int id;
  char cpf[MAX];
};
```

This is how I'm reading it:

```
 printf("| Digite seu CPF: ");
 fflush(stdin); 
 fgets(cdto[autoincrement].cpf, (MAX-1), stdin);
```

Comment: Do you need to store the modified string, or do you simply need to display it?  Do you know that the string is 11 digits long?  Note that you can use `sizeof(cdto[autoincrement].cpf)` instead of `(MAX-1)` — `fgets()` handles newline and null at the end of string (keeping the newline).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Hey, the size of the string, its always 11, but this post from @roottraveller isn`t working, do you know something else?

Comment: I only need to display it

Answer (score 1):

Arrays have static size and so don't expand dynamically.  If your aim is to print the string in the format you mentioned above, below code should help you.

```
int main()
{
    char tempstr[16];
    sprintf(tempstr, "%.3s.%.3s.%.3s-%s", cdto.cpf, cdto.cpf+3, cdto.cpf+6, cdto.cpf+9);
    printf("%s\n", tempstr);    // 123.456.789-00
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed to thank you!